# Combining like data from columns into single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I'm trying to combine partial contents of rows that are the result set of a query from SQL Server 2005 that reads a .CSV. Here's a simplified version of the data I have:

```
objectID  | value1   | value2
_________________________________
12        | R        | 100
12        | R        | 101
12        | S        | 220
13        | D        | 88
14        | K        | 151
14        | K        | 152
```

What I'm trying to get to is a grouping of each objectID's values on the same row, so that there is one and only one row for each objectID. In graphical terms:

```
objectID  | value1a  | value2a  | value 1b  | value2b  | value1c  | value2c
______________________________________________________________________________
12        | R        | 100      | R         | 101      | S        | 220
13        | D        | 88       |           |          |          |
14        | K        | 151      | K         | 152      |          |
```

Blank cells are blank.

I've been hoping to do this in Excel or Access without VB, but CONCAT and other similar functions (and responses here and elsewhere suggesting similar approaches) don't work because each value needs to stay in its own cell (this data will eventually be merged with a Word form). If the answer's a SQL stored procedure or cursor, that's okay, though I'm not terribly efficient at writing them just yet.

Thanks to all.

Comment: Where is your data right now? SQL Server, Access or Excel?

Comment: Google the term "Pivot table" plus the particular platform your data is on

Comment: p.campbell: It's in a CSV and the business end of F5 on SQL Server 2005.

Comment: This will involves dynamic sql trickery, since your column-count will be dynamic according to max # of rows per objectID

Answer (score 4):

First import the data into a temp table. The temp table will end up something like this sample data:

```
create table #tmp (objectID int, value1 char(1), value2 int)
insert #tmp select
12 ,'R', 100 union all select
12 ,'R', 101 union all select
12 ,'S', 220 union all select
13 ,'D', 88 union all select
14 ,'K', 151 union all select
14 ,'K', 152
```

Then, you can use this SQL batch - which can be put into a Stored Procedure if required.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
select @sql = ISNULL(@sql+',','')
        + 'max(case when rn=' + cast(number as varchar) + ' then value1 end) value' + cast(number as varchar) + 'a,'
        + 'max(case when rn=' + cast(number as varchar) + ' then value2 end) value' + cast(number as varchar) + 'b'
from master..spt_values
where type='P' and number between 1 and (
    select top 1 COUNT(*)
    from #tmp
    group by objectID
    order by 1 desc)

set @sql = '
    select objectID, ' + @sql + '
    from (
        select rn=ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by objectID order by value2), *
        from #tmp) p
    group by ObjectID'

exec (@sql)
```

Output

```
objectID    value1a value1b     value2a value2b     value3a value3b
----------- ------- ----------- ------- ----------- ------- -----------
12          R       100         R       101         S       220
13          D       88          NULL    NULL        NULL    NULL
14          K       151         K       152         NULL    NULL
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
```